# React Native app is getting crashed on launch - only on certain Android & IOS devices

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

My react native app is getting crashed only on specific android and ios devices and my crashlytics report says something that is not clear for me. The following is the stack trace for the android app crash i received from Crashlytics. (The initial version of the app was successfully working on these devices. New packages that we added for this release are react-native-firebase, redux and react-native-device-info)

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is not an object (evaluating 'n[1].match(/[A-Z]/g).join'), stack:
<unknown>@352:820
<unknown>@352:814
v@2:1496
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@340:277
v@2:1496
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@339:118
v@2:1496
d@2:949
o@2:435
<unknown>@11:71
v@2:1496
d@2:879
o@2:435
global code@843:4

       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Affected Devices:

So far this has happened consistently in 2 devices (that too in clients device).

Android

> Brand: samsung SM-A730F RAM free: 2.33 GB Disk free: 28.83 GB Version:
>   8.0.0 Rooted: No

IOS

> Model: iPhone 7 Plus RAM free: 157.27 MB Disk free: 67.7 GB Version:
>   12.1.4 (16D57) Jailbroken: No

We tried in almost 20 real devices and none of those devices are getting this crash which makes me very difficult to solve this issue.

React Native version:

```
react: 16.6.1
react-native: 0.57.7
```

Major packages used in this app:

```
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.4"
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
"react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1"
"react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3"
```

Any help on resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the regex `.match(/[A-Z]/g).join')` is being called on a null object. Are you using regex in your app? If so check to make sure that you are not accessing null values before performing the regex

Comment: @Andrew  This null object exception due to regex matching is happening somewhere inside the react-native npm package. So not sure why and for what purpose they are using this regex matching. Also, the same code is working on majority of other devices which makes things weird. The app is getting crashed even without loading the splash screen which means that it is not even executing any of the functionalities / codes written by me. So i suspect some react native modules initialization is causing this crash...!! correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException` is thrown when there is an exception in the javascript. I have had this error when it has been something in my javascript code.

Comment: @Andrew if that is the case, why it is working fine in majority of devices and not in some specific devices ? My understanding is that the react-native is trying to get some device specific data (may be from logged in Google accounts or Itunes accounts etc. ) and trying to match with a regex. In the case of affected devices, this data is coming as null which is causing the issue. In the case of mine, these devices are having active accounts like Google and Itunes. Not sure what data is coming as null as the exception message is not that informative..!